# Hide form A show form B, then hide form B show form A Java JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, hide, show

I have two form in JFrame Form let say Form A and Form B

I have button in Form A to show Form B and hide Form A.

I want to have button too in Form B to show back previous Form A (not create new instance) and dispose Form B.

Any clue of doing this? Thanks.

My Code at this time:

```
private void buttonAActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    FormB formB = new FormB();
    formB.setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false);
}

private void buttonBActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    FormA formA = new FormA();
    formA.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
}
```

EDIT:

Found the solution, make Form A to static and global so can called in Form B. thanks

Comment: Change the scope of `formA` so that the button listener on form B can access `formA`.

Comment: Wow it is that simple. Thanks, my bad, i'm too much code Android now confused in Swing

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)  Either a `CardLayout` for the content of both frames, or one of the frames as a (possibly) modal dialog would be best here.

Comment: *"Found the solution, make Form A to static.."*  Using `static` is more a sign of bad design than of a good solution.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thx for the link, i'll adjusting my app to not use multiple JFrames

Comment: *".adjusting my app to not use multiple JFrames"*  That is good news.  Your users will thank you (well OK, they won't thank you personally, but at least they won't curse you from afar).  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a public static synchronized method to return the form and create it if is null.

FormA.java

```
/**
 *
 * @author joepa37
 */
public class FormA extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private static FormA f = null;

    public FormA() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static synchronized FormA getInstance(){
        try {
            if (f == null) {
                f = (FormA) Class.forName("FormA").newInstance();
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        return f;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        titleLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        goToBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        dataTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        dataLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        titleLbl.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Calibri", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        titleLbl.setText("FORM A");

        goToBtn.setText("Go to FORM B");
        goToBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                goToBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        dataLbl.setText("Data:");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(dataLbl)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(dataTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 161, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(goToBtn)
                    .addComponent(titleLbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 198, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(94, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(titleLbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(goToBtn)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(dataTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(dataLbl))
                .addContainerGap(122, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void goToBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        FormB.getInstance().setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
    }                                       

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                FormA.getInstance().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel dataLbl;
    private javax.swing.JTextField dataTxt;
    private javax.swing.JButton goToBtn;
    private javax.swing.JLabel titleLbl;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

FormB.java

```
/**
 *
 * @author joepa37
 */
public class FormB extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private static FormB f = null;

    public FormB() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static synchronized FormB getInstance(){
        try {
            if (f == null) {
                f = (FormB) Class.forName("FormB").newInstance();
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        return f;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        titleLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        goToBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        dataTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        dataLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        titleLbl.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Calibri", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        titleLbl.setText("FORM B");

        goToBtn.setText("Go to FORM A");
        goToBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                goToBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        dataLbl.setText("Data:");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(dataLbl)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(dataTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 161, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(goToBtn)
                    .addComponent(titleLbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 198, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(94, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(titleLbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(goToBtn)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(dataTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(dataLbl))
                .addContainerGap(122, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void goToBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        FormA.getInstance().setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
    }                                       

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel dataLbl;
    private javax.swing.JTextField dataTxt;
    private javax.swing.JButton goToBtn;
    private javax.swing.JLabel titleLbl;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**Remember to change**  `f = (FormB) Class.forName("FormA").newInstance();`
`Class.forName("FormA")` and `Class.forName("FormB")` Remember that the parameter string must be the path of each file.